# 404 (Not Found) error on calling local backend APIs in angular universal

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

I have implemented angular universal in my project for performance and SEO reasons! every thing works fine when I 'run ng serve' , the app can communicate with backend , but when I run 'npm run build:ssr 'and then 'ng run serve:ssr' it gives me the 404 (Not Found) for all API calls and does not render the entire app.
I would appreciate it if someone could help me .
thanks.

[image]

this is my server.ts file

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/angular-universal/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Answer (score 0):

**If server.ts contains api**

As you have mentioned here you are running `npm run build:ssr` and afterwards ng run serve:ssr. But about the backend, in your server.ts file there are no routes exposed for api calls in this server. So it is obvious that the result is 404. If you are trying to expose apis from the express server then you would need to define api routes. But in your given code the portion for api calls are commented.

```
 // Example Express Rest API endpoints
 // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
 // Serve static files from /browser
```

I had work in similar projects. While running under localhost first you would need to expose the api and make sure that calls are being made on the right port.

**If different backend for api**

If you have a different server for api calls (not the given server.ts) then running `ng serve` would only run the angular portion of your app. So both ends (that is the angular app and server for api calls) are running separately. In this case upon running `npm run build:ssr` and `npm run serve:ssr` you are running angular-universal along with the express server. They are both running on port 4000 as your server.ts file indicates hence angular is looking for apis on the express app where there are no apis exposed and hence resulting in 404. In this case running angular-universal and the api backend on a different port is an easy solution.

Are you trying to use this server.ts (angular universal server) as backend? Or you have different server for api calls. Further clarification is needed

Comment: I have a different backend for api calls! I added this piece  of code ```const apiProxy = proxy('/api', { target: 'http://localhost:8086' });
  server.use('/api', apiProxy); ``` and it is working but the backend still does not understand some of the calls even though the status is 200!

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to mean by "backend still does not understand some of the calls even though the status is 200!". Can you please elaborate a bit more.